# What is the Music called which is played when antagonists are plotting something?

Tags: music, rurouni-kenshin

I am not a fan of questions like this myself, but I am really curious and I couldn't find any answers. I searched through the whole OST myself.

I am looking for the music which is often played when the antagonists are plotting something. A good example is Season 1, Episode 19, directly after the Opening, when Raijuta is introduced.

It is quite fast-paced, with a repeating melody, kinda synth-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for Kokoro no Hadaka. It's typically referred to the Raijuta theme. It's by Ueda Yuji.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHl_sYLLktw

Here's a list of all of RuroKen's OSTs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Rurouni_Kenshin_soundtracks

This one is the fourth track in the Rurouni Kenshin Original Songs I soundtrack.

Comment: Thank you very much, I only searched in the OSTs I-IV :)